# Angular Validation: Validate/Highlight child input on button click

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular 6 here:

I have a parent component and within that I have a child component. The child component has a text fields. The parent has a submit button.

On the submit click button, I want to validate all the inputs of the child as they are required and throw error accordingly.

I am using reactive forms and was successfully able to pass form info from parent to child. But I am not sure how to highlight my text input when the submit button is clicked.

I have used $touched property on my child, which works and shows the required error. But I want the error to also show in case user just clicked the button.

Here is some relevant code.

```
--Parent--

<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <child [myForm]="myForm"></child>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<br>
Form Valid:  <pre>{{myForm.valid}}</pre>

export class AppComponent {
  myForm: FormGroup

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      uname: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('value: ', this.myForm.value);
    console.log('the whole form and its controls: ', this.myForm)
  }
}

--Child--

<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <label for="myForm" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': myForm.controls?.uname.errors }">
      <input type="text" formControlName="uname"  placeholder="Enter Name...">
      <em *ngIf="myForm.hasError('required', 'uname') && myForm.controls?.uname.touched">*Required</em>
    </div>
  </div> 

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() myForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

I have also created a demo to show this at:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbevnj

FYI, this is just a sample I created to show my issue. I would be having 2-3 child components and few form controls on each.

Any inputs how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We resolved this by calling `markAsTouched` on all form controls when submitting the form.

In your case you can add `this.myForm.get('uname').markAsTouched();` to your `onSubmit()` method.

Comment: Not sure I understand how to do what you said. My submit button is on parent and input control on child. Also even if someone doesnt touches the control and just clicks the button I want to show the error on the input.

Comment: I updated your stackblizt onSubmit method. Check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfwlyk) . When you click submit, you control is invalid, but the error is not displayed because the control is not touched, but if you mark you control as touched in submit method, then the error is displayed. Was this the issue or I misunderstand?

Comment: While this works but this means, if we have 10 controls on a page then we would have 10 statements as above. I was thinking if when the submit button is click, pass that value to the child control and in some event of child control get that value and show the error accordingly. Not sure if this can be done.

Comment: You could just iterate over formGroup controls and mark all controls as touched